# How to check for 0 objects in the value field of an NSDisctionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a NSDictionary (MyDictionary) which is currently returning "0 objects" for the 
   [mylist] key:value pair.

```
MyDictionary:
{
    mylist =     (
    );
}
```

How can I check if the value for the key contains 0 objects?
I've tried the following without success:

```
if([MyDictionary objectForKey:@"mylist"] !=[NSNull null]){} //evaluates to false

if([MyDictionary valueForKey:@"mylist"] !=[NSNull null]){} //evaluates to false
```

Comment: Read the dump.  You have a dictionary containing one element.  That element has a value that is an NSArray.  The array is empty.  To tell if it's empty, access it (`MyDictionary[@"myList"]`) and test the `count` of the returned NSArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSNull is not the same thing as nil.

```
NSArray *myList = MyDictionary[@"mylist"];
if (myList.count == 0) {
    //empty or nil!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your dictionary has one key-value pair, where the value is an empty NSArray.  Note that an empty NSArray is *not* the same as an `NSNull` object, nor is it even a `nil` pointer.  It is in fact, a valid pointer to an `NSArray` object that just happens to have nothing in it.

To determine that there are no elements in the array, you must first extract the array from the dictionary, and then check the `count` of the array to determine whether it has any elements. This can all be done in one line of code like this

```
if ( [MyDictionary[@"mylist"] count] == 0 )
    // array is empty
```

Answer (score 0):

The value is an array. To check if an NSArray is empty, you can check whether its length is 0.